# Azure Cognitive Search - Connect to SQL

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a Azure Cognitive Search Service and trying to Connect to an Azure SQL Table.

The Azure SQL has Public Access disabled and a Private Link is created.

I have created a Azure Cognitive Search Service and a Private Link for the same.

The Search service has Managed Identity enabled. The Managed Identity has been given access to the SQL Database and Server.

Now when I try to create a data source the error being returned is
**Failed to create data source "search-ds", error: "Failed to fetch"**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

BR

Answer (score 1):

This documentation topic gives the most comprehensive tutorial to use private link with Azure Cognitive Search indexers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-howto-access-private?tabs=portal-create%2Cportal-status

It has a troubleshooting section near the end.

One of the things it mentions that seems easy to miss is the configuration of the indexer to work in private mode:

```json
{
    "name": "indexer",
    "dataSourceName": "your-datasource",
    "targetIndexName": "index",
    "parameters": {
        "configuration": {
            "executionEnvironment": "private"
        }
    },
    "fieldMappings": []
}
```

Beside the private link aspect, the regular advice also applies, and a lot of things can prevent the indexer from connecting to the data source. Here's another topic that covers other possible causes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-troubleshooting